# Does Mediawiki need to be installed twice to support a second website in another language?

Tags: mediawiki, internationalization, language, wiki

I have a wiki which has English as the default language. Now I want the same wiki in "Malayalam". I already have the translated contents with me.

How do I achieve this?
**Should I create a sub-domain? If yes, then what? Install media-wiki again?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily but it would require considerable time to tweak your wiki. See here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Multilingual_MediaWiki

Note that if you had both languages on the same wiki, you would not be able to:

- Getting an index of all pages or recent changes across languages
- Maintaining a single watchlist across multiple languages
- Using special pages across a set of languages.

It may be complicated to go with this first option.

There is a translate extension which might help. See here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Translate

Alternatively, given that you already have the translated contents, I would recommend setting up either a subdomain or directory and installing a second installation of MediaWiki there.

The two mediawikis 
domain.com/mal/wiki or mal.domain.com/wiki
domain.com/eng/wiki or eng.domain.com/wiki or domain.com/wiki